# Seeking FOSS licensing software

Tags: php

It doesn't have to be uncrackable, just enough to dissuade casual attempts at hacking.

FOSS - usable in commercial projects.

Limit number of consecutive sessions.

I have my own ideas as to how to code it simply. But why reinvent the wheel?

---

Edit: To limit the number of consecutive session I was thinking of a simple counter in the databse (obfuscated somehow), which increments on login and decrements on logout. The tricky part is when someone closes the browser (and their session) without loggin out.

Comment: I dont understand what you are looking for. What is that software going to do? Please add some more information.

Comment: Your question is slightly ambiguous, but I presume you mean open source software that you can use to protect your commercial project, rather than trying to protect an open source project? (since the latter would clearly be a contradition in terms)

Comment: +1 Yes, that's correct. I want to produce something which, while it is  unlikely to earn me more than beer money (if that), is nonetheless commercial. I am just about to add some basic licensing & thought that this particular wheel must have been invented before, so maybe I can resuse someone else's code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't even begin to imagine why FOSS licensing software would exist, this is exactly the kind of anti-feature that the whole FOSS movement was created to work against.  I will be highly surprised and my monocle will pop off my face if I learn that such a thing exists.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to reply. You know, I do agree with you, but .. well, maybe I ought to have said FOSS-friendly or similar, but there are some people who are willing to develop s/w, would much prefer that it is free, but can accept that some folks will use it for commercial porpoises.    Personally, I put bread on the table by coding 9-5, but code in free time coz I can't play guitar; and I don't care who might "exploit" my hobby-coding (ymmv & no offence intended). Lets see if there is any

Comment: Well, if you're just looking for a binary obfuscater/compression you can try UPX, but that's very well known and rather trivial to crack (because it's for compression, not for obfuscation/anti-reversing.)  But as far as "limiting consecutive sessions," I don't honestly know what that means, perhaps you meant "limiting concurrent sessions?"  As in you don't want several people in one place using the software at the same time?  There isn't any good ways to do that other than the registration and phone home manner, which requires you to run a server and continue running it in perpetuity.

Comment: +1  (and, yes, "concurrent" - darned spear chucker!!)  I'll update the question